# Move many repos into one repo folder

Tags: github, repository, project

**Hello Everyone**

I am currently working on The Odin Project. I have all my projects as seperate repos. I am trying to clean up my github and put them into one whole repo to view instead having them everywhere and potentially mean people miss on other projects because there is soo many.

My question is, should I just stick to not having the commit history and move the projects into one repo. Or is there an actual way to do it without it looking like a link if that makes sense so I will be able to remove the previous repo.

Thank you for your help!

### What I have Tried

1. I have just copied the files and added them to the repo- Means no commit history from past repo
2. Submodules, just acts like a link for me when I actually want to physically move the repo from one into the new one so I can delete the old one.

I have tried to use ChatGPT but it seems to go in circles and then when I mention the errors it starts being a bit thrown off and then takes me back to doing submodule way or give the option to have it without commit history